# Error message: line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls

Tags: r

When reading a xlsx file in R, I run into error messages:

> Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,
> :    invalid multibyte string at
> 'z4<91><95>w<8e>r<t'

In addition: Warning messages:

> 1: In read.table("Online_Retail.xlsx", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE) :
> line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls .....
>
> 4: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec =
> dec,  :   embedded nul(s) found in input

I have tried the R codes: `read.table('xxx.xlsx', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)` but it didn't work.

Comment: `read.table` can't read xlsx files as per my understanding goes , use `readxl::read_excel` to read excel files. read.table is used for reading text files or some other flat formats usually

Comment: @PKumar Hi! Thanks for the advice. `readxl` library works but I got warming message: Warning messages:                                           
1: In read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  :
  Expecting numeric in A299984 / R299984C1: got 'A563185'